# ASP.Net C# - GridView Date Column print "MM dd, yyyy DDDD"

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview

I have a gridview with column "Date", I want to print it in this format **MM dd, yyyy DDDD**.

I have this on my .aspx class:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="MyDateTime">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="<%#Item.MyDateTime.Value.ToString("MM dd, yyyy DDDD")%>"
                        runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

But I keep getting this error:
**Parser Error
The server tag is not well formed.**

I can't see which tag is not well formed. If i don't include "MM dd, yyyy DDDD", the code does not have this error, but does not print the way I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using single quotes like:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%#Item.MyDateTime.Value.ToString("MM dd, yyyy DDDD")%>' runat="server" />
```